# Windows 10 lost internet connection even though wireless card is connected to router

Tags: networking, internet

Since I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 I have this internet connection issue. After a restart internet will continue working for about 3 or 4 hours. Then all application, including web browser, teams, etc, will loose internet connection even though wireless card is still connected to my router. First I thought it's the onboard wireless card in Lenovo T440P. I bought a new wireless card. The same thing happens. I have to restart the laptop in order to resolve this internet issue. Anyone has any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a driver issue.  The only thing you changed was software.  So the solution is software.  Make sure you have the latest version of your wireless drivers.  If you already have latest version, try downgrading and see if that doesn't fix the problem.  Check your windows logs to see if there are any errors that pertain to the wireless.  If its happening 3-4 hours after restart, maybe a specific event is happening.  If so it should show up in the logs.

Comment: Thanks for help. I notice it's the Sophos VPN client software causing the issue. After connected to VNP server it will disconnect after 2 or 3 hours. At the same time the internet connection seems to get lost. However I can see the wireless card is still connected.